# intStream Python

Tags: python, потоки-данных

Решаю задачу с codewars, возникла проблема: не знаю, как запустить стрим в питоне. Вот ссылка на неё.

```
https://www.codewars.com/kata/5519a584a73e70fa570005f5/train/python
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как работать со stream в питоне, и, если нетрудно, покидайте примеров с бесконечным потоком.

Comment: IntStream - это пример из java. Для python аналогом будет объект-генератор или итератор.

Comment: Окееей, беру свои слова обратно. Можете кинуть несколько примеров на питоне, пожалуйста?

Comment: Первая ссылка в поисковике по запросу "python генератор"

Answer (score 0):

```
variable=(2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17)
import itertools
varible2=map(bytes,variable) #изменяем тип с инт на байтовый
infinity=itertools.cycle(variable2) #создаём безконечный список
#list(infinity)не исспользуй это
for it in infinity:
   print(it)
#2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 172, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 172, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 172, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 172, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 172, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 172, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 172, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17..........
```

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что данная программа не пройдет тесты к задаче по ссылке